# Swift NSData Initialiser

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsdata

I im tring to implement this method from a Obj-C library.

```
func bleDidReceiveData(data: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>, length: Int32) {
    var d = NSData(bytes: data as [UInt8], length: length)
}
```

However when i tried initializing NSData, it gave me this error

`Cannot find an initialiser for type NSData that accepts an argument of type (bytes:[UInt8],length:int32)`

In Obj-C it is being done this way

```
NSData *d = [NSData dataWithBytes:data length:length];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func bleDidReceiveData(data: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>, length: Int32) {
    var d = NSData(bytes: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(data), length: Int(length))
}
```

Comment: Or just `let d = NSData(bytes: data, length: Int(length))`. A `UnsafePointer<Void>` parameter accepts arguments of other pointer types.